# Конфликт после слияния веток Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

Слил "бранч-2" с master-бранчем. Вылезла куча конфликтов - в ручную профиксил. Теперь в статусе - пишет что ветки идентичны, но когда запускаю приложение с master:а - выдает ошибку **Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""**, а когда делаю чекаут и запускаю с "бранч-2" - все работает нормально. Хотя с фигурными скобками там вроде все в порядке. Где-то вычитал что проблема в sass. В файле-стилей (custom.css.scss) 3500 строчек, как выявить где ошибки?

Comment: ну дык разминимизировать, если было, посмотреть на номер строки и с ошибкой, и там искать упущеную `}` - наверняка какой-то вложеный стиль даёт сбой

Comment: Сделайте diff между ветками, посмотрите, где исчезла скобка

Comment: Спасибо, diff помог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

команда

```
$ git diff ветка-1 ветка-2
```

должна показать отличия в файлах между ветками.

среди этих отличий можно будет найти и пропущенную скобку.